# Why is this put request causing CORS errors when I have a cors header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, cors

Okay, so I am trying to write a put request that will search for a user in my DB by their email, then update the user's profile with data passed along in the request.

here is the put request in my server's app.js

```
app.put("/account/edit", auth, (request, response) => {
    const { name, email } = request.body;
    const filter = {email: request.user.userEmail};
    const update = { name: {name}, email: {email}};
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
        .then((result) => {
            response.status(200).send({
                message: "Edit Successful",
                result,
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.status(404).send({
                message: "User not found/updated",
                error,
                });
        })
        })
    }
)
```

After committing this change, suddenly none of my server requests work. Even logging in, registering a new user, they all give CORS errors which they did not give before I added this bit. I have tested it, and it is this change causing the issue.

Prior to this, this is how I handled CORS errors. I got this from a tutorial and it has worked for me so far.

```
// Curb Cores Error by adding a header here
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
  });
```

So I must've somehow broken something with the edit account API I'm trying to write.

Here is the frontend where I call the API, EditProfileForm.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();
const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

function EditProfileForm() {

    const [ user, setUser ] = useState({name:"", email:""});

    const saveChanges = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = user.name;
        const email = user.email;
        const configuration = {
            method: "put",
            url: "MYURL/account/edit",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            data: {
                name,
                email,
            }
        };
        axios(configuration)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                error = new Error();
            })
    }

    // useEffect executes once the page loads 
    useEffect(() => {
        // set configuration for API call
        const configuration = {
            method: "get",
            url: "MYURL/account",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        };
        axios(configuration)
            .then((result) => {
                //assign the User to the in result to User we initialized
                setUser(result.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                error = new Error();
                window.location.href="/";
            });
    }, []);

    return(
    <div className="edit-account">
        <form className="edit-profile-form">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p className="edit-form-tag">Name:</p>
                    <input 
                        className="edit-form-input" 
                        id="edit-name"
                        value={user.name || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, name: e.target.value})}
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p className="edit-form-tag">Email:</p>
                    <input 
                        className="edit-form-input" 
                        id="edit-email"
                        value={user.email || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, email: e.target.value})}
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => saveChanges(e)}>Save Changes</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}

export default EditProfileForm;
```

and here is the error for trying to login. I get the same error for any API calls now

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MYURL/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Okay, so I deleted the entire put request from my app.js - everything fixed. Then I added it back line-by-line to see where the error arises and it was after I added the line

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
```

Any idea why this could be causing a CORS error for all of my API's?

EDIT - it was the await. Got rid of that and now every API except for this one works again. Now I just gotta figure out why this one is failing with an internal server 500 error

Comment: did you try using post instead of put?

Comment: @EfraimJerszurki I just tried that and it gave me the same errors.

Comment: Use this header header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', you wanna accept al, because it comes from your local host.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the cors error (API still doesn't work but that is a whole other issue) by removing the await at
await User.findOneAndUpdate